# Optional column in pdf after fop xslt transformation

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements, apache-fop

I have a xslt transformation from xml to pdf using apache fop. Whether is possible to add codnition to xslt transormation? I want to not display column in result pdf if all values in column equals zero. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, you can do declarative/functional programming logic with XSLT using templates, functions and conditionals. Since you did not provide any example code, I will suppose that you have a table element in your xslt, and you want to show it only if there is some non-zero value to be displayed.

In this case, you should use an recursive template to walk along the list in your xml, and keep checking with XPath if the values are equal to zero. If you find zero, call this same template for the next value, if not, call the template that builds the table for you.

Notice that to use condition, you can use xsl:for-each, xsl:when or xsl:if elements to make the decision given the XPath expression. The xsl:template is used for iterating recursively with parameters, given that instance variables do not exist in xsl.